# Toggle haml accordion

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, haml, accordion

I have an accordion from an image that says "Tell Me More" that shows a list when clicked. Right now the accordion is automatically set to show the full list and then when clicked collapses the accordion. I want it to do the opposite- to have the list initially collapsed. Any ideas on how to do this?

```
.row.featurette#feature3
  .accordion#accordion
    .accordion-group
      .accordion-heading
        %a.accordion-toggle{'data-toggle' => 'collapse', 'data-parent' => "#accordion", 'href' => '#collapse1'}
          .col-sm-2.col-sm-offset-5.text-center
          =image_tag "tell_me_more.jpg", class: "img-responsive"
      .accordion-body.collapse.in#collapse1
        .accordion-inner
          .col-sm-10.col-sm-offset-1   
            .col-sm-10.col-sm-offset-1.methods.text-center
              %dl 
                %h5
                  %span 1.
                %dt Sample Text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) method to hide it.

```
$('.collapse').hide();
```

And use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method to reveal or hide on click.

```
$('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('.collapse').toggle();
});
```